# Linker pointer wont store or increment in c++

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

My objective is to create a linker struct and then insert new links in alphabetical order using an add_ordered function and then print them in alphabetical order as well. It seems as if my pointer '*p' in the add_ordered function doesn't increment which is the core of my problem.
Any help will be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void print_all(struct Link *p);


struct Link{

    const string name;
    const string mythology;
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;

    Link(const string& b, const string& m, Link *p=0, Link *s=0)
        :name(b), mythology(m), prev(p), succ(s){} //Constructor
};

Link* add_ordered(Link *p, Link *n)
{
    //cout << "Name" << p->name << endl;
    if(n==0) return p;
    if(p==0) return n;

   // cout << "next" << p->succ << endl;

    while(p)
    {

        if(p->name > n->name)
        {
            cout << p->name << " " << n->name << endl;
            n->succ = p;
            if(p->prev) p->prev->succ=n;
            n->prev = p->prev;
            p->prev = n;


            //cout << "word" << endl;
            return n;
            //cout << "COOL" << endl;
        }
        //cout << "Howzit" << endl;

        p = p->succ;

    }
}

int main()
{
    //Create new pointer 'Gods' of type Link.
    //NB!! Gods is a pointer.
    Link* gods = new Link("Posidon", "Greek");
    add_ordered(gods, new Link("Thor", "Norse"));
    add_ordered(gods, new Link("Freia", "Norse"));
    add_ordered(gods, new Link("Athena", "Greek"));
    add_ordered(gods, new Link("Odin", "Norse"));
    add_ordered(gods, new Link("Zeus", "Greek"));
    add_ordered(gods, new Link("Apollon", "Greek"));

    print_all(gods);

    //cout << gods->name << endl;
    return 0;
}

void print_all(Link *p)
{
    cout << "{";

    while(p)
    {
        cout << p->name;
        if(p = p->succ)
            cout << ",";
    }
    cout << "}";
}
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with C# so I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that you do not allow the first pointer to change, once you create the first node

```
Link* gods = new Link("Posidon", "Greek");
```

then gods can never point to another node since your add_ordered function prototype does not allow this

```
Link* add_ordered(Link *p, Link *n)
```

Instead to change p you need to either pass the address of p or actually return something after the while statement  (which you also forgot to do - if it is not a copy/paste issue on your part).

```
Link* add_ordered(Link **p, Link *n)
```

Another thing that you are not doing right is comparing the names, as you have it now you are comparing the addresses of the names, not the names themselves. Fix this by using strcmp i.e.

```
if ( strcmp(p->name, n->name) == -1 )
```

### EDIT:

You should return the first element of the list. That way you can change that inside your function, then you do not need to pass the address of the first element to the function.

```
gods = add_ordered(gods, new Link( ... ));
```

Inside your function add_ordered you check if the link should come in front, then just modify the new element to point to the old element that gods pointed to.

```
if ( strcmp(..) )
{
   p->prev = n;
   n->succ = p;  // this becomes the new first element
   n->prev = NULL;
   return n;
}
else // find where it should be inserted
```

Comment: Oh ok I see the mistake now. I do return n at the end of the while loop? Should it rather return after the while loop?

Comment: Okay I've just tried it and it gives me the error that i cannot convert Link** to Link*?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Claptrap . I think i found a solution but im not too sure as to why it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I call the function the following way then it works but why would assigning my link pointer gods to a function even make sense? Thanks again for the expertise.`

```
Link* gods = new Link("Posidon", "Greek");
gods =add_ordered(gods, new Link("Thor", "Norse"));
gods =add_ordered(gods, new Link("Freia", "Norse"));
gods =add_ordered(gods, new Link("Athena", "Greek"));
gods =add_ordered(gods, new Link("Odin", "Norse"));
gods =add_ordered(gods, new Link("Zeus", "Greek"));
gods =add_ordered(gods, new Link("Apollon", "Greek"));`
```